# Looking for a 70's movie I think

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find the title of a 70's movie where two factions work to win over one guy that knows how to set off  a nuclear bomb.  One faction is known as PAX.  There was an underground subway system in the movie - key to getting around.  Ultimately the guy set off the Nuke for the good of neither faction as I recall.  Good plot.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184456/story-identification-movie-man-put-into-sleep-chamber-building-destroyed-ar (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [Genesis II](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_(film)), which was a feature length pilot for a TV series.

The lead character is Dylan Hunt (not the one from Andromeda, but you can see parallels with Roddenberry's later projects), who is cast into the future.

He is awoken in a post-apocalyptic future by members of PAX, who use a *subshuttle* (subterranean transit system) to get around.

There is another faction, Tyranians, in conflict with PAX, and who want Hunt to reactivate a nuclear missile (knowledge of nukes was lost in the apocalypse). In the end, Hunt sabotages the missile. The movie ends with a setup of having Hunt being welcomed by the PAX, despite his actions going against their pacifist ideals

Answer (score 3):

I ran a quick Google search for "movie pax nuclear" and found a possible match: [Genesis II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_(film)).

[image]

The movie has a protagonist named Dylan Hunt that goes into suspended animation and wakes up over a hundred years later. He is found by a group (PAX) whose members are descendants of NASA scientists, and are pacifists. Hunt later encounters a group of mutants called Tyranians that force him to reactivate a nuclear missile system, which he later detonates to destroy the antagonists.