# Story Identification - movie - man put into sleep chamber, building destroyed around him

Tags: story-identification, movie

In this movie, probably from the 70's or 80's, the man is put inside of some sort of sleep chamber. Something happens to cause the building he's in to be destroyed. It crumbles around him but (miraculously) doesn't destroy the chamber.

He wakes us to a future where the people may be ruled by a strong authority. If I remember correctly, there may be some sort of general uniform people wear.

I remember something about a stunning type of weapon that is used???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the movie you remember is a 1970s TV movie, it might be *Genesis II* March 29, 1973, produced by Gene Roddenberry, in which a 20th century man named Dylan Hunt finds himself in a distant post-apocalyptic future.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_(film)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_(film))

If the movie you remember is a 1970s TV movie, it might also be *Planet Earth*, April 23, 1974, set in the year 2133, produced by Gene Roddenberry.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Earth_(film)[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Earth_(film))

If the movie you remember is theatrical comedy film, it could be *Sleeper* in which a man from 1973 is Frozen and revied 200 years in the future.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_(1973_film)[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_(1973_film))

And there might be a few more such movies from the 1970s and 1980s that I didn't think ov.

Comment: Genesis II is the movie I remember. Thanks!!